# dealing with typedef and pointer

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

Currently, i'm facing some difficulty on understanding the concept of typedef that have a pointer. let say we have this:

```
struct command
{
    int type;
    int *input;
    int *output;
    union{
        struct command *command[2];
        char **word;
    }u;
};

typedef struct command *command_t;

command_t read_command(){
    command_t main1;
    command_t main2;
    //some code that set the instance of main1
    //some code that set the instance of main2
    if(main1->u->command[0] == main2->u->command[1])
    {
        main1 = *main2;
        main2 = NULL;
    }
    //some other code in here
}
```

my question is, since the command_t defined as a pointer to command. in the if statement, should i dereference the main2 first before putting the instance of main2 to main1? if i do something like this, I thin the statement "main2 = NULL;" will not set the object main1 to NULL, right? Thank you.

Comment: "`main2 = NULL;` will not set the object `main1` to `NULL`, right?" - well, why wouldn't it? What else would it do?

Comment: Replace `command_t` with `command*` in the function if it would help you to think about the pointers without worrying about the typedef.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
main1 = *main2;
```

Is wrong regardless. The two are of the same type. You should not deference either in assignment (except the case where you dereference both).

Schematically, what you did (without the dereference) is like this:

```
main1 --> some_object;
main2 --> some_object2;
```

Becomes

```
main1 --> some_object2;
main2 = NULL;
```

You lose the reference to `some_object`, it doesn't zero it out or frees it.

Comment: however, since the typedef defined command_t as a pointer to command, i think the command "main1=main2; main2=NULL;" will set main1 to NULL. right?

Comment: @JessicaHerlian, no. Each pointer is like a slip of paper with an address. Wiping one clean doesn't affect what's written on the other. Even if they both have the same address written on them.

Answer (score 0):

main1 = main2 makes main1 point to the same object that main2 points to.
main2 = NULL sets the pointer main2 to NULL but does not affect main1.  The object is not changed by either assignment.